# Selenium webdriver not closing giving no attribute error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using Selenium along with Python for a project I am working on that launches a webdriver using a gui. However when the `Quit` button is pressed and runs the CloseBrowser() method **while the webdriver is running** it returns an exception of `Browser` object has no attribute 'driver'. I've tried to move the thread and the function for the closing browser to the other class but didn't help.

**EDIT:** I have fixed my program by removing one of the classes and combining the program into one class. Still not sure why that worked and the previous 2-class method didn't

```
import tkinter as tk
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import threading
import random
import sys 
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime 
from tkinter import messagebox
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import *


class InstagramBot():
    # Run page
    def Gui(self):
    # Load application

        try:
            root = tk.Tk()
            root.lift()
            root.title("Instagram Bot - Created By HudZah")
            menubar = Menu(root)

            print("Application loading, please wait \n\n")
            print("When you install this application, you agree to the abide by the Terms And Conditions stated in the installtion folder. This software is not intended to be used for the exploitation of Instagram, rather as a means of promoting your product. Any detention or suspension that is resulted due to excessive use of this Bot is in no means the fault of the publisher, but the consequences faced by the user. It should be clear that this Bot should not be misused or overused, this might result in unknown penalties to be faced by the user." + "\n Created by HudZah") 

            Border = 3

            MEDIUM_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
            LARGE_FONT= ("Arial", 12)


            # Creating Canvas
            canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=630)
            canvas.pack()
            MainFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
            MainFrame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

            # Adding file menu and commands
            file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
            menubar.add_cascade(label = "Run", menu = file)
            file.add_command(label ='Run', command=lambda:self.Threader(Username.get(), Password.get(), List.get(), PicsInput.get())) 
            file.add_separator() 
            file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = root.destroy) 

            # Username label
            UsernameFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", bd=Border)
            UsernameFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.135, relwidth=0.60,
                                relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

            Username = ttk.Entry(UsernameFrame, font=LARGE_FONT)
            #Username.insert(0, "Username")
            Username.insert(0, "HudZah")
            Username.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
            Username.focus()

            # Password label
            PasswordFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", bd=Border)
            PasswordFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.26, relwidth=0.60,
                                relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

            Password = ttk.Entry(PasswordFrame, show="*",  font=LARGE_FONT)
            #Password.insert(0, "Password")
            Password.insert(0, "HUdhayfart_123")
            Password.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

            # Hashtags label
            ListFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgrey", bd=Border)
            ListFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.385, relwidth=0.60,
                            relheight=0.1, anchor="n")

            List = ttk.Entry(ListFrame, font=LARGE_FONT)
            #List.insert(0, "Explore Hashtags, eg: food, nyc")
            List.insert(0, "minecraft")
            List.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

            # Number of pictures dropdown
            PicsInput = Spinbox(root, from_= 5, to = 2000, font = LARGE_FONT)
            PicsInput.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.61, relwidth=0.14,
                        relheight=0.055, anchor = "n")


            # Run button
            button = ttk.Button(MainFrame, text="Run",
                            command=lambda:self.Threader(Username.get(), Password.get(), List.get(), PicsInput.get()))

            button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.71, relwidth=0.25,
                        relheight=0.085, anchor="n")           

            # Quit button
            Quitbutton = ttk.Button(MainFrame, text="Quit",
                            command= lambda:self.CloseThreader())

            Quitbutton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.81, relwidth=0.25,
                        relheight=0.085, anchor="n")


            label = ttk.Label(root, text = "Created by HudZah © 2019", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
            label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.93, anchor = "n")

            PicsInputLabel = ttk.Label(root, text = "Pictures Per Hashtag", font=MEDIUM_FONT)
            PicsInputLabel.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.55, relwidth = 0.3, anchor = "n")

            # Create label to show errors to users and Info of bot when closed
            root.config(menu = menubar)
            root.mainloop() 
        except Exception:
            print("Failed to create gui")

    def CheckUserInfo(self, username, password, hashtagReceived, nOfPics):


        browserCount.append(nOfPics)
        if username and username != "Username":
            pass
            if password and len(password) > 5:
                pass
                if hashtagReceived and hashtagReceived != "Explore Hashtags, eg: food, nyc":
                    pass
                    if int(nOfPics) > 0 and int(nOfPics) < 2000:
                        browserRunning = Browser().IsBrowserRunning(browserCount)
                        print(browserRunning,browserCount)
                        if browserRunning == False:
                            if messagebox.askokcancel('Application','Application is running, press OK to continue') == True:

                                try:
                                    pages = int(nOfPics)/10
                                    pages = int(pages)
                                    if pages < 1:
                                        pages = 1
                                    else:
                                        pass

                                except Exception:
                                    messagebox.showwarning("Error", "An error has occured")

                                infoError = False

                        else:
                            messagebox.showerror("Multiple Instances", "Only one instance of the program can be run at a time. Please wait")
                            print("Only one instance of the program can be run at a time!")

                    else:
                        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter a valid number of posts to like")
                        print("Please enter a valid number of posts to like")                      
                else:
                    messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter your correct information.")
                    print("Please enter suitable data")
            else:
                messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Please enter your correct information.")
                print("Please enter suitable data")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning('Error', 'Please enter a username or password')
            print("Please enter a username and password")

        try:
            if infoError == False and browserRunning == False:
                BrowserClass = Browser()
                BrowserClass.Login(username, password, hashtagReceived, nOfPics, pages)

            else:
                print("Multiple instances or wrong information\n")
        except:
            pass

    def Threader(self, username, password, hashtagReceived, nOfPics):

        #Start a new thread to run the webdriver seperately to stop the gui from freezing
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.CheckUserInfo, args = (username, password, hashtagReceived, nOfPics))
        t1.start()

    def CloseThreader(self):

        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.CloseBrowser)
        print("Close threader")
        t2.start()
        #self.CloseBrowser()


    def CloseBrowser(self):
        try:
            driver = Browser().driver
            driver.quit()
            print("Browser quit\n")
            browserRunning = False
            browserCount.clear()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass

class Browser():

    def Login(self, username, password, hashtagReceived, nOfPics, pages):

        browserRunning = True
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        hashtags = []
        hashtags = hashtagReceived.split(",")
        hashtagsOut = False
        i = 0



        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
            time.sleep(5)


            LoginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
            LoginButton.click()

            time.sleep(5)


            UsernameElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//input[@name='username']")
            UsernameElem.clear()
            UsernameElem.send_keys(self.username)


            PasswordElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//input[@name='password']")
            PasswordElem.clear()
            PasswordElem.send_keys(self.password)
            PasswordElem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

            time.sleep(2)

        except WebDriverException or NoSuchWindowException:
            print("Browser has been closed by manual intervention \n")
            browserRunning = False
            InstagramBot().CloseThreader()
            pass

        else:

            try:
                loginCheck = driver.find_element_by_id("slfErrorAlert")


            except NoSuchElementException:
                infoValidity = True
                pass

            else:
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "Please re-verify your login details")
                print("Login details are incorrect \n")
                InstagramBot().CloseThreader()
                infoValidity = False

        if infoValidity == True:
            for hashtag in hashtags:

                # Choose a tag from the list of tags         
                hashtag = hashtag.replace(" ", "")

                if i != len(hashtags) and hashtagsOut == False:
                    self.LikePhoto(hashtag, nOfPics, pages)
                    i = i + 1

                else:
                    InstagramBot().CloseThreader()
                    hashtagsOut = True

            if i != len(hashtags):
                InstagramBot().CloseThreader()
                print("Browser crashed")
                time.sleep(3)

            else:
                hashtagsOut = True

            if hashtagsOut:
                messagebox.showinfo("Complete", "Program has completed")
                InstagramBot().CloseThreader()

    def LikePhoto(self, hashtag, NumOfPics, pages):

        try:
            driver = self.driver 
            driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
            time.sleep(3)
            PicLinks = []
            print("Check : Number of pages are", pages)

            currentUrl = driver.current_url

            if currentUrl != "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/":
                driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
                time.sleep(5)


            for i in range(0,pages):

                driver.execute_script(
                    "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)


                Links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

                Links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in Links
                        if ".com/p/" in elem.get_attribute("href")]

                for Link in Links:
                    if Link not in PicLinks:
                        PicLinks.append(Link)

                print(
                    "Check: Total N.of pic hrefs stored after array : " + str(len(PicLinks)) + " , in " + hashtag)

            LikedPhotos = 0 # FIX LOST CONNECTION and LIKED TOTAL LIKED PICS


            for i in range(0, len(PicLinks)):
                print("Num" , i , ": " ,  PicLinks[i])

            UniquePhotos = int(NumOfPics)
            print(UniquePhotos)

            # For all the images in the array, like each one
            for i in range(0,int(NumOfPics)):
                try:
                    driver.get(PicLinks[i])
                    time.sleep(4)

                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass

                try:
                    driver.execute_script(
                        "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

                except NoSuchElementException as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass

                time.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))

                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@aria-label="Like"]').click()


                time.sleep(1)
                UniquePhotos = UniquePhotos - 1
                LikedPhotos = LikedPhotos + 1
                print("Picture liked : ",LikedPhotos , " Pictures left : ", UniquePhotos)

        except NoSuchWindowException or WebDriverException or NoSuchFrameException as e:
            print(e)
            browserRunning = False

        finally:
            print("LikePhotos function is now over\n")
            InstagramBot().CloseThreader()
            browserRunning = False

    def IsBrowserRunning(self, browserCount):
        if len(browserCount) > 1:
            print(len(browserCount))
            return True

        else:
            return False




if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Run from main \n")

    NewLimit = 3000
    sys.setrecursionlimit(NewLimit)
    global browserCount
    browserCount = []


    IG = InstagramBot()
    IG.Gui()

else:
    print("Run from import")
# if IG.CheckUserInfo() == False:
#     print("yes")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to modify your code.

```
class Browser():

    driver = None
    def Login(self, username, password, hashtagReceived, nOfPics, pages):
        try:
            self.__class__.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver = self.__class__.driver
```

You put webdriver.Chrome() in Login function.

So you should call Login() before CloseBrowser.
Or you will get None.